# Telegram Bot does not receive updates for inlineKeyButton with url click

Tags: telegram-bot

I have my telegram bot in chat and I need receive updates when some user click inlineKeyButton with url. But I can not receive this updates with webhook. I can receive update for callbackQuery, bit not for url. Are here some ways to receve update when inlineKeyButton with url clicked?

Press inlineKeyButton with url, but there are no updates.

Answer (score 0):

`url` in `inlineKeyboardButton` does not send any callback, it directly opens the URL instead. It works this way by design.

Quoting the [docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton):

> **InlineKeyboardButton**
>
> This object represents one button of an inline keyboard. You must use **exactly one** of the optional fields.

So you either have `url` or `callback_data`, you can't have both.